# Javascript works in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have the following script to set top-margins on elements in a site's nav:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var height = $('.top-band');
        $('.logo-container').css({ 'margin-top': height.height() + 2 });
        var heightHeader = $('.site-header')
        $('#nav-main .site-nav').css({'margin-top': heightHeader.height() / 3 });
    });
</script>
```

It works in all browsers except Firefox (I'm testing on Firefox 60.0.2). Any ideas on what the issue might be are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does “working” and “not working” mean? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. You forgot to add `px` to your margins.

Comment: Top-margin values are applied as expected to targeted elements in all browsers except Firefox. Dev tools shows no errors. while troubleshooting, I added a console.log message inside the function this is printed by Firefox, but again, the script is not.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment because I exceeded the 5-min limit for edits: Sorry, that was not a good explanation. Top-margin values are applied as expected to targeted elements in all browsers except Firefox. In Firefox, the values are applied, but incorrectly. For example, top-margin applied to .logo-container is 40.4 px. However, the height of .top-band is 30px, so the applied value should be 32px. Dev tools shows no errors.